# How to dynamically add a new column to a Datagridview using Entity Framework for Windows form

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework, dynamic

My database object is the below class using Sqlite. I could easily bind this class to datagridview Windows form using the code below :

```
public partial class ClientSystemHardware
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int client_number { get; set; }
    public string client_name { get; set; }
    public string pc_manufacturer { get; set; }
    public string pc_architecture { get; set; }
    // etc…
}

clientHardwareEntities _dataObject = null;

private void LoadDataSource()
{
    string dbName =  GetDBName(1);

    try
    {
        _dataObject = new clientHardwareEntities(dbName);
        dataGV.DataSource = _dataObject.ClientSystemHardwares.ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex.InnerException != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.Message, "Erreur", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Erreur", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
}

private void btnValidate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        dataGV.EndEdit();
        _dataObject.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Erreur", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly);
    }
}
```

I’m using Entity Framework v6.3000 for .NET 4.0 with `System.Sqlite.dll` v1.0113.

I would like to add a new column dynamically which contains the line number which shouldn’t interfere while using Entity framework DB context savings.

Could you give me some guidelines please ?

Comment: You can manually add a column to the `DataGridView` that is “not” attached to the grid’s `DataSource.` Obviously, your code will have to manage “what” values are in each cell of that column. Example, if the data source is sorted, the added detached column will “not” sort with the data source. This works well for things like a button column or possibly some static count column. If you need the column to sort with the data source, then you should add the column to the data source itself. It is unclear what purpose the column serves.

Comment: Thanks JohnG for your answer. I already did it in some of my projects without using Entity Framework, using only System.Sqlite.dll, autogenerating columns = false, and adding my own columns, changing the order, sorting and saving etc.., obviously it's a tedious work, I would like to know if there is any other esay ways to do it without repeatedly reinventing the wheel using EF.

Comment: I am not following what you mean by _”… repeatedly reinventing the wheel using EF”_ ? If the code is adding the column to the grid, then this would have nothing to do with EF. In other words, once the column has been added, you should not have to re-add the column later even if the data source changes. Obviously if the columns are cleared, then you will need to add the column again. I may not be understanding what the problem is.

Comment: Hi JohnG, Could you please give me a link or a sample , how to attach a column that s not attached to the Datasource. Thank you in advance

Comment: If autogenerate columns is set to false, then you “must” be adding the columns in your code. How are you currently adding the columns to the grid? You can add the columns in the designer or it is straight forward to add the columns manually… something like… `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn col = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn(); dgv.Columns.Add(col);` If the column is added in the designer, then I assume that column’s `DataPropertyName` is left blank.

Comment: I am guessing that what you are talking about is how the “detached” column is “cleared” when the data source is sorted or changed. In addition, if the grids data source changes, then the detached column will be cleared and moved to the first column. In these cases, you will need to re-fill the detached columns cells with data and possibly reset its display index.

Comment: I suggest you [edit] your question and clarify what is not happening as you want. I will not argue that re-setting the detached columns values may be cumbersome, however, if the code is in a method, you could call this code after the grid sorts or data source changes.

Comment: Thanks JohnG for your advise. You gave me a hint. I found what i needed. (adding unbound column to bound datas).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear what type the grids data source is. I assume it is either a `DataTable` from SQLite or a `List<ClientSystemHardware>`. From your comment I am guessing you want a column…*”which contains the line number”* … is referring to a “row” number in the grid. If this is the case, then one possible solution is below.

Instead of messing around with an added column, take advantage of the grid’s `RowHeader` column. If we create a method that sets each row header to that rows index value. Then we will not have to add the column to the grid. In addition, you could possibly set `AutoGenerateColumns` to `true` and remove the code that manually adds the columns. However, you will still need a method to set the row header values, and it may look something like…

```
private void setRowHeaderValues() {
  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) {
    if (!row.IsNewRow) {
      row.HeaderCell.Value = (row.Index + 1).ToString();
    }
  }
}
```

We could call this method after the data has loaded into the grid... however, there are two places where this code would need to be called to maintain a consistent ordering… 1) when a row is added  2) when a row is deleted. With these two methods wired up, then we do "not" have to call the method when the grid's data source is loaded or changed.

For adding and removing rows…

```
private void dataGridView1_RowsRemoved(object sender, DataGridViewRowsRemovedEventArgs e) {
  setRowHeaderValues();
}

private void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e) {
  setRowHeaderValues();
}
```

Drop a `DataGridView` onto a form along with a button and copy the code below to test this. Note the code is NOT adding columns to the grid. The code uses the columns from the DB. …

[image]

```
DataTable GridTable;

public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  GridTable = GetDataFromDB();
  dataGridView1.DataSource = GridTable;
  dataGridView1.RowHeadersWidth = 60;
}

private void setRowHeaderValues() {
  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) {
    if (!row.IsNewRow) {
      row.HeaderCell.Value = (row.Index + 1).ToString();
    }
  }
}

private DataTable GetDataFromDB() {
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Columns.Add("Col0", typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add("Col1", typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add("Col2", typeof(string));
  for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    dt.Rows.Add("C0R" + i, "C1R" + i, "C2R" + i);
  }
  return dt;
}


private void dataGridView1_RowsRemoved(object sender, DataGridViewRowsRemovedEventArgs e) {
  setRowHeaderValues();
}

private void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e) {
  setRowHeaderValues();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  GridTable = GetDataFromDB();
  dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
  dataGridView1.DataSource = GridTable;
}
```